# Create sqlite db using bookshelf.js

Tags: database, node.js, sqlite, bookshelf.js

How to create a new sqlite3 database file using bookshelf.js? If db file exists, connect to it; If db file doesn't exists, create a new db file.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under the hood, `bookshelf` uses `knex` (which in the current version you have to explicitly use to instantiate).

If you set the client to be `sqlite3` in the options, and you specify a valid path in the `connection` object (property `filename`) then it will connect or create as required (caveat: assuming you have read/write to the file destination).

The reason a database file isn't just created is that you have to do a write first - so try creating a schema ([knex schema builder](http://knexjs.org/#Schema)). Then you should see the file is created.

To be a little more explicit - here's kind of what you are looking for:

```js
var path = require('path')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , knex = require('knex')
    , bookshelf = require('bookshelf')
    , dbFile = path.join(__dirname, 'app.db')
    , db = null // bookshelf db instance

// init db
db = bookshelf(knex({
    client: 'sqlite3'
    , connection: { filename: dbFile }
}))

// create a schema if no db found
fs.exists(dbFile, function(exists) {
    if (!exists) {
        db.knex.schema.createTable('test_table', function(table) {
            table.increments()
            table.string('some_col')
        })
    }
})

// ... do other stuff here ...
```

Comment: I think knex creates the file when creating the connection, so you're probably better off using `createTableIfNotExists`